# Question within a sentence

Tags: grammar, punctuation, questions

I know what I'm trying to get at with this sentence, but the punctuation feels a little off to me somehow. Is it correct? Or can it be improved?

> I was a little skeptical at first - what could be more straightforward
>   than CSS? - but I use it in all my projects now.

Comment: Why does the punctuation "feel a little off"? Could you be more specific?

Comment: I suppose I'm not sure whether the hyphens around the sub question are a good idea or whether they are incorrect here

Comment: The more conventional way to punctuate it would probably be to either drop the question mark or to turn it into two sentences by dropping the dash and capitalizing *"But"*.

Comment: en-dashes or em-dashes are used as parentheses. The keyboard shortcuts are; left Alt + 0150 and left Alt + 0151 respectively. Insert spaces before and after an en-dash, no spaces used with an em-dash. The only 'offness' I get is from the ending where I would place the 'now' after 'but'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with inserting a parenthetical question—for isn't that what you intended there?—that interrupts the flow of a declarative sentence. Do not use hyphens, however. Use em dashes:

> I was a little skeptical at first—what could be more straightforward than CSS?—but I use it in all my projects now.

Some stylists prefer actual parentheses instead of em dashes:

> I was a little skeptical at first (what could be more straightforward than CSS?) but I use it in all my projects now.

Either way, the interruptive effect is similar to that of *metanoia* ([see item "d" from my reference to Ward Farnsworth's illumination of the topic](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2567/explicitly-correcting-yourself-while-writing-how-appropriate-is-it/2570#2570)), and the practice can be a valid and attractive way to vary sentence patterns.